# Subquery returned more than 1 value, don't see how this can happen

Tags: sql-server

I know the error is really clear but I can't seem to find why it would return more then 1 result, what do I do wrong?

I want to know how many weeks are left between the start date of a project in this current year. So I calculate the difference in weeks between the startdate and enddate with datediff. After making sure both dates are in this year. I've been checking numerous other questions but couldn't find a similar problem because datedif only returns 1 value. Thanks in advance.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fWksInCurrentYr] (@projectId int)

RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
DECLARE @sDateCY DateTime
DECLARE @eDateCY DateTime
DECLARE @startCY DateTime
DECLARE @endCY DateTime
DECLARE @returnvalue int

SET     @startCY = DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,getdate()), 0)
SET     @endCY = DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,getdate()) + 1, -1)
SET     @sDateCY = (SELECT ServiceRequest.StartDate FROM dbo.ServiceRequest WHERE dbo.ServiceRequest.[Project_ID] = @projectId)
SET     @eDateCY = (SELECT ServiceRequest.EndDate FROM dbo.ServiceRequest WHERE dbo.ServiceRequest.[Project_ID] = @projectId)

SET     @sDateCY = CASE 
            WHEN @sDateCY < @startCY THEN @startCY
            ELSE @sDateCY
            END
SET     @eDateCY = CASE
            WHEN @eDateCY > @endCY THEN @endCY
            ELSE @eDateCY
            END

SELECT TOP 1 @returnvalue=IsNull(datediff(ww,@sDateCY,@eDateCY),0)
RETURN @returnvalue

END
```

And if I then use this query I get the error:
SELECT [dbo].[fWksInCurrentYr] ([Project].[ID])
FROM [Project]

Comment: Run this query `SELECT Project_ID, count(*) FROM dbo.ServiceRequest GROUP BY [Project_ID] Having count(*) > 1`. All the Project_ID which have multiple records will cause this issue. May be try to add distinct when selecting startdate and enddate, see if that resolves that problem. But using distinct won't guarantee if you will not recieve this error in future.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was indeed the problem, I've altered it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following:

```
SET     @sDateCY = (SELECT TOP 1 ServiceRequest.StartDate FROM dbo.ServiceRequest WHERE dbo.ServiceRequest.[Project_ID] = @projectId)
SET     @eDateCY = (SELECT TOP 1 ServiceRequest.EndDate FROM dbo.ServiceRequest WHERE dbo.ServiceRequest.[Project_ID] = @projectId)
```

Or you can write it a bit more elegantly something like this...

```
SELECT TOP 1 @sDateCY = ServiceRequest.StartDate  
            ,@eDateCY = ServiceRequest.EndDate 
FROM dbo.ServiceRequest 
WHERE dbo.ServiceRequest.[Project_ID] = @projectId
```

*Note*

You cannot return data from a query and assign values to a variables at the same time but you can assign values to multiple variables at the same time Like I have done in my suggested solution.

Comment: Depending on your requirements, you might need `min(startdate)` and `max(enddate)` instead of `top 1`

Answer (score 0):

You had written

```
    SET     @sDateCY = (SELECT ServiceRequest.StartDate FROM dbo.ServiceRequest 
WHERE dbo.ServiceRequest.[Project_ID] = @projectId)
```

Instead of this, try this

```
    SELECT  @sDateCY = ServiceRequest.StartDate FROM dbo.ServiceRequest 
WHERE dbo.ServiceRequest.[Project_ID] = @projectId
```

same for **@eDateCY** variable.

May be solve your problem but not sure it will work or not.

Comment: This would have not made any difference

Comment: @M.Ali: Sure it would.

Comment: @Arvo how are these two statement any different from each other?

Comment: @M.Ali, the first one i ANSI standard and gives an error if 0 or more than one row is returned. The second is SqlServer extension and uses the last value returned (or does not change `@sDateCY` if no rows are returned). I.e. the second one is good if you want to hide errors and make debugging harder :-)

Comment: Good god from where did you get this information? the first one will return an error if no row is returned from the select statement and the second one will not? really?? can you prove this? with a sql fiddle or something ?

Comment: @adrianm It will not throw an error if no record is returned in both statement. And it will throw an error in both statements if more than one row is returned. The only difference is how you assign the value to your variable. The statement itself can have anything in it, MIN(), MAX(), SUM() whatever as long as it returns a scalar value and the returned value's data type is compatible with the variable data type you can assign it either way.